# how to insert xml string as XML node into dom element in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader, xmldom

I have to insert a XML string into specific node.

```
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("Project");


/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);
$projectInfo=createProjectInfo();//this will return xml string <ProjectInfo>Some text here</ProjectInfo>

$xmlRoot->loadXML($projectInfo);//here i am getting  "Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::loadXML() in."
```

Here is what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <ProjectInfo>Some text here</ProjectInfo>
</Project>
```

It's different than what the others suggested; here, I am dealing with the string xml not xtml.

Comment: you say that `$projectInfo=createProjectInfo()` returns a `string` not a `DOM element`?

Comment: The code which tells you how to use `createDocumentFragment` is the most relevant part for this.

Comment: @RamRaider yes createProjectInfo() return string only